# How to make a bar plot showing different months in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

I have this data set.

```
##          Jan        Feb        Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul
## 1 0.05266167 0.11384153 0.14253802 0.1507699 0.1571320 0.1121953 0.1647502
## 2 0.09274933 0.11954029 0.17114252 0.1644035 0.2030245 0.2571798 0.1824315
## 3 0.12873033 0.15829162 0.19940906 0.1804324 0.2239007 0.2279327 0.2416183
## 4 0.06973417 0.05635917 0.06897862 0.1149706 0.1121177 0.1182867 0.1173400
## 5 0.15117362 0.10942123 0.12451943 0.1702807 0.2135427 0.2164273 0.2075777
## 6 0.41753005 0.34718628 0.29915414 0.2856211 0.4458226 0.5053402 0.6380533
## 7 0.43642524 0.37800174 0.27653371 0.3551805 0.3233486 0.3996235 0.4975522
## 8 0.21988812 0.22843585 0.23984762 0.2705450 0.2058714 0.2185158 0.2564072
##          Aug       Sep       Oct        Nov        Dec Units     Annual
## 1 0.19781433 0.1566800 0.1901342 0.09750671 0.08782510   m/s 0.14005536
## 2 0.27276717 0.2393716 0.1152078 0.09969814 0.09888717   m/s 0.17627843
## 3 0.25592567 0.2641575 0.1358387 0.17679250 0.15574617   m/s 0.19947550
## 4 0.06964667 0.1165557 0.0852325 0.08210633 0.06016383   m/s 0.09029416
## 5 0.15983400 0.1917124 0.2359582 0.15190757 0.14265571   m/s 0.17288818
## 6 0.48610683 0.4169365 0.4343557 0.36020295 0.48484231   m/s 0.41894140
## 7 0.43456983 0.3914535 0.3669773 0.36234052 0.40674304   m/s 0.38100448
## 8 0.31760617 0.3240705 0.3552170 0.25114412 0.22125319   m/s 0.26848028
##   Direction RecpDir       Code      Means
## 1         N       S 0.03335250 0.13532074
## 2        NE      SW 0.07719650 0.16803361
## 3        E        W 0.07318150 0.19573130
## 4        SE      NW 0.05302025 0.08929099
## 5        S        N 0.02574475 0.17291754
## 6        SW      NE 0.03034450 0.42676267
## 7        W        E 0.03523275 0.38572913
## 8        NW      SE 0.01729375 0.25906683
```

I need to make a bar plot that shows the wind velocity for January through December. Each month has 8 rows of data that need to be combined into 1 using the 'mean' function. How would I get the mean for each month and then turn this into a bar plot? I need the x-axis to have each month labeled, with an axis title of "Month" and the y-axis title to be "Velocity (m/s)". I have included the data below.

```
 structure(list(Jan = c(0.0526616666666667, 0.0927493333333333, 
 0.128730333333333, 0.0697341666666667, 0.151173619047619, 0.417530047619048, 
 0.436425238095238, 0.219888119047619), Feb = c(0.113841531746032, 
 0.119540285714286, 0.158291619047619, 0.0563591666666667, 0.10942123015873, 
 0.347186277777778, 0.378001738095238, 0.228435849206349), Mar = c(0.142538023809524, 
 0.171142523809524, 0.199409055555556, 0.0689786190476191, 0.124519428571429, 
 0.299154142857143, 0.276533714285714, 0.239847619047619), Apr = c(0.150769928571429, 
 0.164403476190476, 0.180432404761905, 0.114970595238095, 0.170280738095238, 
 0.285621119047619, 0.355180452380952, 0.270545), May = c(0.15713196969697, 
 0.203024523809524, 0.223900714285714, 0.112117666666667, 0.213542666666667, 
 0.445822642857143, 0.323348571428571, 0.205871396103896), Jun = c(0.11219530952381, 
 0.25717980952381, 0.227932666666667, 0.118286666666667, 0.216427333333333, 
 0.505340214285714, 0.3996235, 0.218515833333333), Jul = c(0.164750166666667, 
 0.1824315, 0.241618333333333, 0.11734, 0.207577666666667, 0.638053333333333, 
 0.497552166666667, 0.256407166666667), Aug = c(0.197814333333333, 
 0.272767166666667, 0.255925666666667, 0.0696466666666667, 0.159834, 
 0.486106833333333, 0.434569833333333, 0.317606166666667), Sep = c(0.156680025974026, 
 0.239371555555556, 0.26415753030303, 0.116555720779221, 0.191712357142857, 
 0.4169365, 0.3914535, 0.3240705), Oct = c(0.190134166666667, 
 0.115207833333333, 0.135838666666667, 0.0852325, 0.235958166666667, 
 0.434355666666667, 0.366977333333333, 0.355217047619048), Nov = c(0.0975067142857143, 
 0.0996981428571428, 0.1767925, 0.0821063333333333, 0.151907571428571, 
 0.360202952380952, 0.362340523809524, 0.251144119047619), Dec = c(0.0878250952380952, 
 0.0988871666666667, 0.155746166666667, 0.0601638333333333, 0.142655714285714, 
 0.484842311688312, 0.40674303968254, 0.22125319047619), Units = c("m/s", 
 "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s"), Annual = c(0.140055362193362, 
 0.176278428571429, 0.199475503607504, 0.0902941623376623, 0.172888182539683, 
 0.418941396825397, 0.381004476190476, 0.268480282828283), Direction = c("N", 
 "NE", "E ", "SE", "S ", "SW", "W ", "NW"), RecpDir = c("S", "SW", 
 "W", "NW", "N", "NE", "E", "SE"), Code = c(0.0333525, 0.0771965, 
 0.0731815, 0.05302025, 0.02574475, 0.0303445, 0.03523275, 0.01729375
 ), Means = c(0.135320744348244, 0.16803360978836, 0.19573130477393, 
 0.0892909945887446, 0.172917541005291, 0.42676267015392, 0.385729134259259, 
 0.259066833934584)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data reshaping, then plots.

### Base R

```r
datlong <- reshape2::melt(dat[,1:12], id.vars=c(),  variable.name = "month")
datlong[c(1:3, 94:96),]
#    month      value
# 1    Jan 0.05266167
# 2    Jan 0.09274933
# 3    Jan 0.12873033
# 94   Dec 0.48484231
# 95   Dec 0.40674304
# 96   Dec 0.22125319
datagg <- aggregate(value ~ month, FUN = mean, data = datlong)
head(datagg)
#   month     value
# 1   Jan 0.1961116
# 2   Feb 0.1888847
# 3   Mar 0.1902654
# 4   Apr 0.2115255
# 5   May 0.2355950
# 6   Jun 0.2569377
month.abb
#  [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
datagg$month <- factor(datagg$month, levels = month.abb)
```

Simple barplot:

```r
barplot(value ~ month, data = datagg)
```

[image: base graphics barplot]

### dplyr and ggplot2

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
dat %>%
  select(Jan:Dec) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "month") %>%
  mutate(month = factor(month, levels = month.abb)) %>% 
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month, value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: ggplot2 barplot]

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(Jan = c(0.0526616666666667, 0.0927493333333333, 0.128730333333333, 0.0697341666666667, 0.151173619047619, 0.417530047619048, 0.436425238095238, 0.219888119047619), Feb = c(0.113841531746032, 0.119540285714286, 0.158291619047619, 0.0563591666666667, 0.10942123015873, 0.347186277777778, 0.378001738095238, 0.228435849206349), Mar = c(0.142538023809524, 0.171142523809524, 0.199409055555556, 0.0689786190476191, 0.124519428571429, 0.299154142857143, 0.276533714285714, 0.239847619047619),      Apr = c(0.150769928571429, 0.164403476190476, 0.180432404761905, 0.114970595238095, 0.170280738095238, 0.285621119047619, 0.355180452380952, 0.270545), May = c(0.15713196969697, 0.203024523809524, 0.223900714285714, 0.112117666666667, 0.213542666666667, 0.445822642857143, 0.323348571428571, 0.205871396103896), Jun = c(0.11219530952381, 0.25717980952381, 0.227932666666667, 0.118286666666667, 0.216427333333333, 0.505340214285714, 0.3996235, 0.218515833333333), Jul = c(0.164750166666667, 0.1824315,      0.241618333333333, 0.11734, 0.207577666666667, 0.638053333333333, 0.497552166666667, 0.256407166666667), Aug = c(0.197814333333333, 0.272767166666667, 0.255925666666667, 0.0696466666666667, 0.159834, 0.486106833333333, 0.434569833333333, 0.317606166666667), Sep = c(0.156680025974026, 0.239371555555556, 0.26415753030303, 0.116555720779221, 0.191712357142857, 0.4169365, 0.3914535, 0.3240705), Oct = c(0.190134166666667, 0.115207833333333, 0.135838666666667, 0.0852325, 0.235958166666667, 0.434355666666667,      0.366977333333333, 0.355217047619048), Nov = c(0.0975067142857143, 0.0996981428571428, 0.1767925, 0.0821063333333333, 0.151907571428571, 0.360202952380952, 0.362340523809524, 0.251144119047619), Dec = c(0.0878250952380952, 0.0988871666666667, 0.155746166666667, 0.0601638333333333, 0.142655714285714, 0.484842311688312, 0.40674303968254, 0.22125319047619), Units = c("m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s", "m/s"), Annual = c(0.140055362193362, 0.176278428571429, 0.199475503607504, 0.0902941623376623,      0.172888182539683, 0.418941396825397, 0.381004476190476, 0.268480282828283), Direction = c("N", "NE", "E ", "SE", "S ", "SW", "W ", "NW"), RecpDir = c("S", "SW", "W", "NW", "N", "NE", "E", "SE"), Code = c(0.0333525, 0.0771965, 0.0731815, 0.05302025, 0.02574475, 0.0303445, 0.03523275, 0.01729375), Means = c(0.135320744348244, 0.16803360978836, 0.19573130477393, 0.0892909945887446, 0.172917541005291, 0.42676267015392, 0.385729134259259, 0.259066833934584)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. If I wanted to change the "value" on the y-axis to a different label, is there a way to do this in ggplot?

Comment: `+ labs(y = "something")`?

Comment: Yup, that did it, thanks! I've already marked as correct